# How to reshape data frame with multiple columns

Tags: r, reshape

i have a huge data base i need to reshape this is the data:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to reshape based on the variables Hombres_0, Hombres_1,... etc , the variables are more but i need that, thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2tI6.png

Comment: [link](https://uc-r.github.io/tidyr)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common operation， which is transforming data from wide format to long format.

see the link below for example:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/